# Can't use \underset inside \begin{equation}....\end{equation}

Tags: equations

[image]

I am trying to write an equation, as shown above, in `LateX`, and I'm getting an error by using `\underset` with `\begin{equation}...\end{equation}`. An MWE is the following:

```
\begin{equation}
\widetilde{\beta}_{k}^{ridge}=arg \underset{b\in \mathbb{R}^{p+1}}{min}\left \| y-X b \right \|^{2}
\end{equation}
```

PS: I have already loaded `amsmath` package.

Comment: Welcome to TSE. It is in your beste interest that you post a minimal working example, instead of a coding snippet.

Answer (score 3):

Please always show the exact error you got and a complete test document. If you only load `amsmath` you would have an error from `\mathbb` not `\underset`

This works without error

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\widetilde{\beta}_{k}^{ridge}=arg \underset{b\in \mathbb{R}^{p+1}}{min}\left \| y-X b \right \|^{2}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

But never use math italic for multi-letter words so

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\widetilde{\beta}_{k}^{\mathrm{ridge}}=\arg \underset{b\in \mathbb{R}^{p+1}}{\min}\left \| y-X b \right \|^{2}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't get that error if you load `amsmath`.

On the other hand, `\underset` is the wrong tool for the job. Besides, “arg min” is a single operator, so the subscript should cover both parts: it's not “the argument of the minimum”, but “the minimum argument”.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\newcommand{\numberset}[1]{\mathbb{#1}}
\newcommand{\R}{\numberset{R}}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{arg\,min}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\widetilde{\beta}_{k}^{\mathrm{ridge}}=\argmin_{b\in \R^{p+1}}\lVert y-X b \rVert^{2}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\tilde{\beta}_{k}^{\mathrm{ridge}}=\argmin_{b\in \R^{p+1}}\lVert y-X b \rVert^{2}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Some points to note:

1. Operators should be typeset in upright font, which is done by using the proper declaration.
2. Words in subscripts or superscripts should be upright as well.
3. `\left` and `\right` are useless in the context; `\lVert` and `\rVert` are better than the unqualified `\|` (try `$\|-x\|$` and `$\lVert-x\rVert$` for comparison).
4. It's better to avoid filling your paper with `\mathbb{R}` and define a personal command; you'll be grateful having done so when you get the request of your senior coauthor to change all `\mathbb{R}` into `\mathbf{R}`.
5. I also added the version with `\tilde` instead of `\widetilde`, which I prefer.

[image]

Comment: I prefer the second code :-)